# How to see output of invoke expression - IO.MemoryStream

Tags: windows, powershell

```
$s=New-Object IO.MemoryStream(,[Convert]::FromBase64String("some base64 string here"));

IEX( New-Object IO.StreamReader(
        New-Object IO.Compression.GzipStream(
           $s,[IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress) 
)).ReadToEnd();
```

How can I see the IEX's output?

Comment: Invoke-Expression (iex)'s output is not different from anything else. You see the output on the screen, same as any other cmdlet, so there isn't enough information in your question to explain why you can't see the output. Maybe there is no output? Try `iex 1+1` and you see `2`.

Comment: I tried iex 1+1 and see 2 but i do not see in this example, is it perhaps because it's memory stream?

Comment: No; the base64 decode and memory stream decompress should result in a string containing PowerShell code.  IEX runs the code, and at that point it makes no difference where the string came from. Run it without the `iex` and see what the code is.

Comment: that did it! thanks TessellatingHeckler